# How to recreate a query for different version of mariadb (currently: 10.4.27, recreate to: 10.1.38)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS col2_int INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (IF(col1_date IS NULL,0,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(col1_date))) STORED;
```

How do i recreate this for it to work with version 10.1.38 in mariadb

[I'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Zmo.png)

Comment: you can't you need a trigger for that in the older version

Comment: hmm can you please give me an example or something related to this, because im very new to SQL queries?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html